# MissingReferenceExcepetion after deleting an object

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have the following script

```
 using System.Collections;
 using UnityEngine;

public class Bullet : MonoBehaviour
{

[SerializeField]
private float _speed;

private IEnumerator ShootAt(Vector3 target)
{
    while (transform.position != target)
    {
        yield return null;
        transform.localPosition = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.localPosition, target, _speed * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}

private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
{
    if (other.tag == "Animal")
    {
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
}

}
```

After the bullet hits the animal and gets destroyed, I get the following error: MissingReferenceException: The object of type 'Bullet' has been destroyed but you are still trying to access it. Your script should either check if it is null or you should not destroy the object.

The error is referring to the while loop in my code. I guess it's still running that loop because the condition to stop it hasn't been met yet

```
  while(transform.position != target)
```

I tried adding a second condition to stop that loop, like

```
  while(transform.position != target || gameObject != null)
```

but that doesn't seem to work. Any help would be more than appreciated.

Comment: I would write a boolean function to determine if a collision was made. Call that function in your while loop after the `transform` and if it returns true, `break` and do whatever else you need it to do.

Comment: `transform.position != target || gameObject != null` is wrong. You are checking null after trying to retrieve the transform field of the gameObject (that would throw a null exception by itself). Try inverting the checks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apart from some refactoring like another user suggested in the comments, you could try the same logic you have, but reversed:

`while(gameObject != null || transform.position != target)`

The `||` [operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-or-operator) will be evaluated in order it is written, so in your case the `transform.position` is still being evaluated before your null check.

Also, you could consider using `StopCoroutine` prior to calling `Destroy` on your object.

Finally, as I've also personally had trouble with such a case (perhaps related to [this](https://support.unity3d.com/hc/en-us/articles/115000404563-Why-am-I-getting-MissingReferenceException-in-the-Editor-and-a-NullReferenceException-on-mobile-devices-when-running-the-same-piece-of-code-) behavior)

> The only thing that the C# object has is a pointer to the native object, so Destroy(myGameObject) destroys the native object but the managed object in the C# side still exists, and is destroyed when it's no longer referenced and is collected by the garbage collector.

So you might just consider introducing a `isHit` member variable and setting it to true upon a successful collision, followed up with your `Destroy`.

Comment: The last solution you suggested worked perfectly, although the bool has to be a member variable, rather than a local one. This is because it gets set in the OnTriggerEnter2D function but gets read inside of the coroutine.

Comment: Oops, nice catch @CareyOn. That is what I meant. I've updated my answer to reflect that.